# Small calendar with custom events for Rails 3 application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, calendar

I'm looking for jQuery Calendar plugin for my Rails 3 application.

It should look like [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#default), but I would like also to have the ability to add (possibly recurrent) events to it, and see them on date hover.

It is important that the calendar will be small like jQuery's Datepicker. [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), for example, is too big.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Someone favorited this question, but didn't upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attempt to modify jQuery Datepicker to fit your needs. Otherwise I dont see a lot of date plugins that are well supported for jQuery.